# TeX to Word conversion

Tags: conversion

I need to convert `TeX` format files to `Word` format, I knew that lot of questions are already raised for this and lot of answers also there in web, but please provide your valuable suggestions for my task:

Based on the replies and many browse, I've decided to look into the following three converters:

1. `GrindEq`
2. `Chikri`
3. `TeX4ht`

But please suggest which is the best among these, note that for my conversion equations, cross links (both numbered and name&year style in references), Table alignments are the must.

Please give your valuable suggestion on my request...

Comment: There is also another program `latex2rtf` http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: @Sebastiano Hope latex2rtf doesn't support name&year style references (especially natbib.sty options) , please correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: @MadyYuvi development version of `make4ht` supports convrsion to OpenDocument format (`make4ht -f odt filename.tex`). It supports math and tables, but it is best to convert it to DOCX using LibreOffice, because Word's support for ODT files with math is tragic.

Comment: `pandoc`! It can generate docx from markdown and markdown from latex source.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Is pandoc supports equations into mathtype and natbib optios? Those two are my major requirements...

Comment: Have not tried mathtype, it works with bibtex variants. It also works with CSL files for citation styles specific to journals. As an alternative you can always resort to latex escape.